# “bled rags“ or "rugs"?

Tags: word-usage, past-participles

I'm trying to find pictures by googling *bled rugs* or *bled rags*. Can't find anything, not even in the common results.

It seems to me, it's supposed to be perfectly common usage, but the world doesn't think so. What do you think?

Also, dictionary.cambridge.org don't have much of good examples. It's all about *bled animals*. The third form *bled*, seems to be pretty stiff in its usage.

Comment: The principal parts of the verb to bleed are: bleed, bled, bled. "pretty stiff in its usage": What does that mean?

Comment: Hi. What are you looking for? A rug and a rag are not the same thing. What do you mean by "third form"?  Are you talking about a past participle? Your question is confusing. Please edit your question describe what you are looking for using other words. "Bled/bleeding" with regard to fabrics often means the colour dyes have run, which is usually unintentional/accidental. Is that what you mean?

Comment: To make this question answerable, please edit to explain what meaning you're looking for. The phrase "bled rugs" (or rags) isn't really used commonly and it's not clear what you're trying to mean. I'm voting to close this question as unclear until edited.

Comment: Do you know the difference between a rug and a rag? A dictionary will help you, but if you can't tell if something is a rug or a rag then you will have to give us a description or a picture. The people answering questions here are often very clever but they are not mindreaders.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't actually state what you are trying to find, but I suspect your confusion comes from the two different uses of the verb 'bleed'. Persons or animals - things with blood and a circulatory system - can bleed by accident, such as when they sustain a wound. If you cut yourself you might say that you are bleeding, and in the past tense would say "I bled". However, *to bleed* something also means to deliberately drain the blood from a live being, such as is common in preparing an animal to be eaten. To say something has "been bled" in this context means that *all* of the blood has been drained. You can also use 'bled' as an adjective to describe something in this condition.

You said you want a picture of a "bled rag" - does a rag have blood to drain? Are you looking for a '*bloody*' or '*bloodied*' rag, meaning a rag stained with blood?

Or perhaps you are looking for cloth items which have colours or dyes which 'bleed' into one another? This is a different use of the word 'bleed' altogether. In this context, we don't use the adjective 'bled' to describe such a product, even if it is part of the process. We would not say that say a rug was "bled" (adjective). We might say that the colours had bled, or more likely that they had *run*.

Comment: I think some confusion between **rugs** (which sometimes become 'bled') and **rags** (which don't)?

Comment: @MichaelHarvey I don't think we would say a rug was "bled" (adjective). We might say that the colours had bled, or more likely that they had *run*.

Comment: Probably counts as a specialist term. My first wife was a Batik and general textile artist. She has rugmaker friends.  I've seen what she called a 'bled' rug. It can be a disaster for a valuable piece, but sometimes it is induced deliberately, and a 'bled carpet' or 'bled rug'  can be a fashionable home decor choice. Try Googling.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey: I did, and found exactly *one* instance of ["a bled rug"](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22a+bled+rug%22) in Google Books. But the context is pretty definitive: *Be sure the rug doesn't look "bled". **A bled rug is one in which the colors have run**.*

Comment: It seems a reasonable guess that the OP is looking for a laundry-related context, but it's not clear to me. I'd hold off until the answer is more certain.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey Scroll down in the Walmart listing: That's a proper-noun name that's been given to the design, not a descriptor.

Answer (score 1):

Well, I Googled 'bled rug' and immediately found this on a page headed 'Rug Dyes. What makes them bleed'. I would say it's 'common usage' mainly among people who make, dye, or are passionate about carpets, rugs or textile art in general. Not everyone. I would call it a 'specialist term'. My first wife was a Batik and general textile artist. She has rugmaker friends. I've seen what she called a 'bled' rug. It can be a disaster for a valuable piece, but sometimes it is induced deliberately, and a 'bled carpet' or 'bled rug' can be a fashionable home decor choice.

https://rugchick.com/rug-dyes-what-makes-them-bleed/

[image]

[image]

Comment: I removed the dv. Geesus.

Comment: @Lambie - I missed it. Did someone think I had made it up? And faked the picture + caption? My heart would have bled like a rug had I seen it.

Comment: People around here downvote stuff when the answer does not deserve it. Just do not **get it**! :)